# error: The method 'setMapStyle' isn't defined for the type 'Completer'

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esXpf.png)

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to change ma Google maps Color

error: The method 'setMapStyle' isn't defined for the type 'Completer'.

Answer (score 0):

First define the `Controller` for the `GoogleMap`

```
  GoogleMapController mapController;
```

*And now add that `Controller` to set the map style for the map in your GoogleMap Widget.*

```
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    mapController.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
    // _controller.complete(controller);
  },
```